# What is the difference between initial_apicid and apicid in cpuinfo_x86 struct?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, apic

What is the difference between `initial_apicid` and `apicid` in `struct cpuinfo_x86`?
I just saw that in case x2apic is not enable those fields may not contain the same value but is not written any else.